Why does Homset to larger field reveal information about roots?
I am sorry if this question appears very philosophical, but I have been contemplating this for days and haven't found a satisfactory answer. What I have learnt from basic Galois theory is that given a tower $L/F/k$, $Hom_{k-\mathsf{Alg}}(F, L)$ reveals information about $L$-roots of all $k$-polynomials with roots in $F$. For instance, the Galois group $\text{Aut}(F/k)$ is indeed equivalent to $\text{End}_k(F)$ (since field homomorphisms are mono), and tells us about $F$-roots of polynomials by acting faithfully on those of a irreducible polynomial, and moreover transitively if it is the minimal polynomial of a primitive element. In the case of a simple extension, $Hom_{k-\mathsf{Alg}}(k(\alpha), \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the algebraic closure, corresponds precisely to the roots of the minimal polynomial in $\Omega$.
But why does this work? Is there a natural way by which one may have come up with this connection themselves? Even better, is there a way to think of these homsets in a "root-free" way?

You have it backwards. The hom-sets are precisely the way to think root-free. They were invented after, not before.
